# How to sort filtered data?

Tags: angularjs

I have a table of data that I can filter and show only the "Color" rows if I select the "Color Only" item from the sort list. I am doing this by using the following code:

```
<label>Sort By:</label>
<select ng-model="orderProp" class="form-control" tabindex="2">
  <option value="title">Title</option>
  <option value="filename">File Name</option>
  <option value="class">Classification</option>
  <option value="color">Color Only</option>
</select>
```

And then using ng-repeat on the table element:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (pptData | filter: query | orderBy: orderProp)" ng-if="orderProp !== 'color' || item.color">
```

However, how can I display those color results by title? I tried to do the following, but it didn't work:

```
<option value="{{ 'color' | orderBy:'title' }}">Color Only</option>
```

Anyone have any ideas? My [live demo is here](http://ogmda.com/symbols/).

Comment: So, when the user choses "Sort by color only", it should sort by title? That is quite confusing, isn't it? Why do you use the sort combo to filter? Why don't you use a checkbox to filter by color, instead of using a sort option?

Comment: I think he means when you select "only color" which means color=true, then the entries should be sorted by title.

Comment: jedanput is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this,

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (pptData | filter: query | orderBy: [orderProp,'title'])" ng-if="orderProp !== 'color' || item.color">
```

Basically you first sort by orderProp, then by title.

Comment: I re-thought this process and when I tried it this time, it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
$scope.reverse = true; // false

<option value="{{ 'color' | orderBy:title:reverse }}">Color Only</option>
```

reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy